# What new content does City of Heroes: Going Rogue have for existing toons?

Tags: pc, city-of-heroes

Can anyone run through what changes this expansion makes to the game? I have a number of existing characters and I am unable to find any information about how the new content works for existing characters.

I'm currently unsubscribed, but I'm tempted to buy a month to have a run around again.

I've had a poke about in various wiki's and not managed to turn up anything. So does anyone know what changes have been made or how they work with the existing characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going Rogue adds a new zone (Praetoria), which was initially only accessible to new characters created there. As of the current issue, it is now possible for existing characters to travel to the new area.

As for effects for existing characters, provided that you have the expansion all existing characters will gain access to the alignment system which allows characters to change alignments ranging between hero, vigilante, rogue, and villain by completing missions with an associated moral choice (tip missions / morality missions).

If you have the expansion, you automatically gain access to the new powersets, but be aware that much of the content added is in the new zone, so you will either need to start a character there, or move a character there. Praetoria currently (issue 19) has only content in the lower levels (up to about 20) after which point you move to Paragon City or the Rogue Isles.

Finally, to access the new post-50 content (the Incarnate system, which includes additional buffs, and level shifts) you must have going rogue. This applies to both new characters and existing characters.

Comment: In addition, the Incarnate system is only accessible to those characters who own the Going Rogue expansion. You may want to add info about it to your answer

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Heroes):

> Going Rogue: City of Heroes: Going Rogue was released in 2010. Unlike CoV, Going Rogue is an expansion rather than an "Expanshalone" and requires the original game(s) to play. Going Rogue adds an Alignment system, which allows players to switch from Hero to Villain and adds two intermediate Alignments: Vigilante as a player progresses from Hero to Villain and Rogue as a player progresses from Villain to Hero. Players with Vigilante or Rogue characters have access to both City of Heroes's Paragon City and City of Villains's Rogue Isles until they change to Hero or Villain. The expansion also adds the Praetorian Earth dimension where players can start out as neutrally aligned Praetorians (choosing any of the 10 basic Archetypes available to Heroes or Villains), either deciding to side with Emperor Cole's ruling faction and become a Loyalist or side with the Resistance; the allegiance can change as the player choses and completes missions. Praetorian players can also attack new Neutral mobs and will eventually be able to play a mission that will allow them to choose to be a Hero or Villain and complete gameplay in the original games. Going Rogue also grants access to four new power sets, new costume sets and auras, and introduces missions that start after defeating mobs that affect the player's Alignment.

Comment: Yeah, I know that stuff, but what about existing toons? Will my existing toon be able to change alignment? Will I get access to the new missions, new areas and powersets?

Comment: To answer this question: You were previously allowed to take your already existing characters and convert them through a series of alignment missions. So in theory, yes. You could take your Villain and move them to Heroside and vice versa. I do believe you also had the option of VISITING Praetoria but not leveling up there.